# Join 2 tables using cursor/procedure/function

Tags: java, sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE branch (
    branch_code    NUMBER,
    branch_name   VARCHAR2(80)
);

CREATE TABLE client (
    client_nr       NUMBER,
    client_add   VARCHAR2(40),
    client_name     VARCHAR2(60)
);

CREATE TABLE insurance (
    account_no                      VARCHAR2(50),
    insurance_type                VARCHAR2(40),
    insurace_company_code       VARCHAR2(40),
    company_details   VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE TABLE credit (
    account_no             VARCHAR2(40),
    branch_code         NUMBER,
    loan_amount    FLOAT,
    amount _to _refund   FLOAT,
    account_type            VARCHAR2(30),
    credit_type         VARCHAR2(30),
    interest_rate       FLOAT,
    client_nr           NUMBER
);

--INTEGRITY CONSTRAINTS

ALTER TABLE branch ADD CONSTRAINT pk_branch PRIMARY KEY ( branch_code );

ALTER TABLE client ADD CONSTRAINT pk_client PRIMARY KEY ( client_nr );

ALTER TABLE credit
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_client_nr FOREIGN KEY ( client_nr )
        REFERENCES client ( client_nr ) ON DELETE SET NULL;

ALTER TABLE credit
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_branch_code FOREIGN KEY ( branch_code )
        REFERENCES branch ( branch_code ) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

I have to determine the interest rates for each client using a cursor/procedure/function.

I am currently having problems solving this question since I'm getting an error "ora-01422:exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows".I solved it using a select statement but I must use a function/procedure or cursor for my assignment.

Here is the sql select statemnt I used:

```
SELECT
    client.client_nr,
    nvl(interest_rate, 0) dobanda
FROM
    credit
    FULL OUTER JOIN client ON credit.client_nr = client.client_nr
ORDER BY
    client.client_nr;
```

Thank you for taking the trouble to help me.

Comment: It would be better to write a single query with join and do not use cursors as the are less performant, consume more resources and can produce a lot of troubles to you if not managed correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article before posting. Especially ask only one question per post. It is unclear what you are actually asking for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, toydarian .I edited the question ,I hope it is easier to understand what I am asking for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which to use cursor/procedure/function? Well first you need to get a clear mental picture of what each of these are. The following is a **quite simplified version**.

- A cursor is the result of a query. So your solution mentioned is a
  necessary precondition for a cursor. A given cursor has a specific
  query. There is another type called a reference cursor which can hold
  the result of different cursors (but must resolve to a specific
  result set definition eventually). Typically a reference cursor is
  not processed in the where defined/generated while a cursor is
  processed when/where defined.
- A procedure or a function are both programs stored in the database
  and can be used as needed. They are close to the same but have
  different intended usage. In short a procedure performs operations on
  your data, a function retrieves information. Procedure can return
  information via OUT parameters, but that is not the intended use,
  although some times useful. Functions must return a single 'database'
  object. Further functions can usually be called by SQL, a procedure
  cannot be called from SQL.

*Example Procedure processing Cursor*

```
create or replace procedure client_credit_cursor
is 
    cursor c_client_credit is 
        select
            client.client_nr,
            nvl(interest_rate, 0) dobanda
        from
            client  
            left outer join credit  
                    on credit.client_nr = client.client_nr
        order by
            client.client_nr;
            
    client_cursor_rec c_client_credit%rowtype;
    
begin 
   open c_client_credit; 
   loop
      -- process each row from cursor
      fetch c_client_credit 
       into client_cursor_rec;
      exit when c_client_credit%notfound;
      
      -- process single rew returned by cursor
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Client: ' || client_cursor_rec.client_nr || 
                            ' Interest_rate: ' || client_cursor_rec.dobanda 
                          ) ; 
   end loop;
   close c_client_credit;
   
end client_credit_cursor;
```

The above uses what is called an explicit cursor. There is another variation called an implicit cursor. I'll leave that up to your research. The implicit cursor is typically the variation.  

*Example of Function returning a reference cursor.*

```
create or replace function customer_credit_interest
  return sys_refcursor
is
  l_client_credit sys_refcursor;
begin 
   open l_client_credit for 
        select
            client.client_nr,
            nvl(interest_rate, 0) dobanda
        from
            client  
            left outer join credit  
                    on credit.client_nr = client.client_nr
        order by
            client.client_nr;
    return l_client_credit ;
end customer_credit_interest;
```

See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30da0501cbe2cf5ebeb5058503a54c24) for example of each and anonymous blocks running them.